# Adding Data to Amazon RDS through Lambda Function

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I've been trying to create an Alexa skill which is written in nodejs and I wanted to push some data through to an RDS database. I've configured the VPC and security groups which should mean the lambda function has access to the database, as I'm new to writing code in node I think I may have incorrectly written my query function. I have the node-mysql module in my zip file for the lambda function so there are no issues with that.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     :  rds endpoint,
    user     : 'mohammad',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'motivate'
  });

  connection.connect(function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
  });

  for(var i = 0; i < authors.length; i++){
    var postData = {author: authors[i], quote: quotes[i]};

    var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO quotes SET ?', postData, function(err, result) {
      console.log(err);
    });
    console.log(query.sql);
  }

  connection.end();
```

This is all within my exports.handler except for the require('mysql') which is at the very beginning of the code. I assume the code runs successfully as there are no errors and the console prints as follows.

```
2017-01-11T00:20:47.141Z    c41a492d-d793-11e6-8344-27807a741276    INSERT INTO quotes SET `author` = 'Theodore Roosevelt', `quote` = 'Keep your eyes on the     stars, and your feet on the ground.'
2017-01-11T00:20:47.141Z    c41a492d-d793-11e6-8344-27807a741276    INSERT INTO quotes SET `author` = 'Nelson Mandela', `quote` = 'It always seems impossible until it\'s done.'
2017-01-11T00:20:47.141Z    c41a492d-d793-11e6-8344-27807a741276    INSERT INTO quotes SET `author` = 'Og Mandino', `quote` = 'Failure will never overtake me if my determination to succeed is strong enough.' 
2017-01-11T00:20:47.199Z    c41a492d-d793-11e6-8344-27807a741276    New Session
2017-01-11T00:20:47.199Z    c41a492d-d793-11e6-8344-27807a741276    Launch Request
REPORT RequestId: c41a492d-d793-11e6-8344-27807a741276  Duration: 925.98 ms Billed Duration: 1000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB
```

One thing I've noticed is that the console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId); is not being executed as there is nothing in the log. I'm unsure if I've improperly set my connection up in the createConnection portion or if the error is coming from another portion of my code.

Comment: The problem isn't in the query function *per se*.  The most egregious issue: you're running asynchronous things but written in a synchronous style, expecting things to block, which don't... so your code is finishing before any callbacks fire and meanwhile your queries run before the connection is established.  I would be using `async-waterfall` here, but I am something of a novice at Node myself so I hesitate to post an answer.

Comment: Check also that your lambda function has the necessary IAM Role - I didnt see you mention IAM role anywhere

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'll take a look into async-waterfall and see if it can help with my issues. Worth looking at since I'm at a standstill haha

Comment: @Henry My IAM roll consists of the following policies: AmazonRDSFullAccess, AWSLambdaFullAccess, AmazonVPCFullAccess, AWSLambdaExecute, AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole, and AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole. Please let me know if this seems like a properly set up IAM role for connecting between RDS and AWS Lambda.

Comment: Was wondering if you managed to solve it at all ? I am guessing the for loop needs to go insider the connection.connect callback

Comment: Any new solutions?